# How to generate short variable for smallint type columns using JPA Tools in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, jpa, eclipse-mars

I was generating Entity class using **JPA Tools** in eclipse Mars. It generates data member of **Integer** datatype which is **smallint** type in table.I need to generate **short** type of datatype for column which is **smallint** in table.

Comment: In Eclipse  http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jpt.doc.user%2Fref_customizIndividualEntities.htm Customize Individual Entities you can change Mapping type property

Comment: Where can I find Table and columns area?

Answer (score 4):

I think something like this might work :-

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "SMALLINT")
@Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.ShortType")
private short variableName;
```

Comment: I was talking about that JPA Tools should automatically generate short type data member for smallint type column

Answer (score 1):

After entering JPA entities from table wizard after selecting table->table Association->Customize Defaults->customize indicidual Entities .. here you can customize your table

But usually it ll automatically convert smallint type to short.

[image]

Comment: For doing this I have to edit mapping for every column.I have various table, It will be quick if I use find and replace.

Comment: @Varun If the table column type is defined as smallint. the wizard itself by default should map from smallint to short. Please check table column type before generating entity classes. Other than this option i don't know have to check doc.

Comment: The column type in table is smallint but JPA Tools does not map it to short data type. The same issue was with Eclipse Kepler.

Comment: Its not IDE problem i created sample with luna and mars and MySql db it works. what db are you using ?.. and for mapping table type this is only option using JPA tool i checked doc.

Comment: I am using postgresql.